# Como retornar un tipo observable a partir de otro

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Tengo los siguientes métodos que retornan objectos por medio de observable de rxjava

```
 Observable<Store> getStore();
 Observable<Bitmap> getPicture(String path);
```

Quiero retornar un tipo observable

```
Observable<StoreViewModel>
```

Fabrico el objeto a partir del metodo getStore();

```
@Override
    public Observable<StoreViewModel> getStoreViewModel() {

        StoreViewModel storeViewModel = new StoreViewModel();

        return repository.getStore()
                .flatMap(store -> repository.getPicture(store.getPicturePath()),
                        (store, picture) -> {

                    storeViewModel.setName(store.getName());
                    storeViewModel.setPicture(picture);

                            return Observable.just(storeViewModel);
                        });
    }
```

Pero tengo errores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He visto que por medio de flatmapIterable obtengo el observable de storeviewmodel
pero no logro implementarlo

```
flatMapIterable(storeViewModelObservable ->  ??????????????? );
```

Answer (score 0):

No he trabajado mucho con RX pero sé que flatMap recibe una función del tipo A -> B donde A es el tipo del stream al que se le hace flatMap (en este caso repository.getStore() debería devolver un Stream), y B es el tipo del Stream que se obtiene, de cada elemento del stream al que se le hace flatMap. Por ejemplo a una lista de strings se le puede hacer:

```
 .flatMap(string -> Arrays.asList(string.charAt(0), string.charAt(1)).stream());
```

Por lo que es muy raro que en lugar de cerrar tu paréntesis pongas una coma, ya que flatMap sólo recibe una función como argumento, no recibe más de un argumento, incluso el que pones de flatMapIterable, porque cualquier flatMap devuelve otro stream, así que yo creo te hace falta algún filter, después del flatMap(...) para poder devolver un Observable y no un Stream(), a menos que tu Stream sea al mismo tiempo un Observable.
https://www.arquitecturajava.com/rx-flatmap-mergemap-y-simplificacion-de-observables/